# Are directory dots in scandir always first elements of array?

Tags: php, directory, directory-structure, scandir

When using `scandir` in PHP, one always gets directory dots ('.' and '..'). It seems that they are two first elements in array, but will they always be? Is it safe to use something like this to get rid of them?

```
$files = scanf('/images');
unset($files[0]);
unset($files[1]);
```

Comment: The most upvoted user contributed note on the PHP manual' page for `scandir` gives a safe way to remove these dots : http://de1.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't.

When called like that `scandir` will return entries in alphabetical order, which means that if e.g. an entry named `-` exists it will appear before the dot entries. Tthere are also other characters that are widely accepted inside file names but sort before the dot, see an ASCII table for reference.